# Twitter Bootstrap form: Make label column wider

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

the question is about Twitter Bootstrap forms. Does anybody now what's the recommended way to get the left column (with the labels) wider than 140px? It's important that it also looks good on mobile devices.

Thanks for your recommendations.

Answer (score 5):

In Bootstrap v2.1.1, the `.control-label` width is defined in `forms.less` like this:

```
.form-horizontal
{
    .control-label
    {
        width: @horizontalComponentOffset - 20;
    }
}
```

You could override the `@horizontalComponentOffset` variable definition in your project's LESS code after importing bootstrap's `variables.less`. If you need this for a specific page, do it in that page's LESS. Otherwise, add it a common import, or better yet, your own `variables.less` file that is intended to override Bootstrap's predefined variables.

As far as mobile goes, you can use [media queries](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) to give a different `@horizontalComponentOffset` value for mobile devices, if needed.

Answer (score 3):

I tried several ways. Also to add styles within the html file, which looked good on desktop, but not on mobile devices.

The solution is to change the bootstrap.css (though I'm not sure whether this file is intented to be changed):

```
.form-horizontal .control-label {
  float: left;
  /*original: width: 140px;*/
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: right;
}
.form-horizontal .controls {
  /*original: margin-left: 160px;*/
  margin-left: 220px;
}
```

Comment: Editing the library CSS file is almost never a good idea, as it makes upgrading and maintenance a nightmare.

Comment: You can, however, make your own css file which overrides these values.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to edit

```
.form-actions {
    padding-left: 160px;
}
```

as well in forms.less

This should be set as a variable, I think.

I've modified that for me as such in forms.less (the two new variables are set in variables.less then):

```
// Horizontal-specific styles
// --------------------------

.form-horizontal {
  // Increase spacing between groups
  .control-group {
    margin-bottom: @baseLineHeight;
    .clearfix();
  }
  // Float the labels left
  .control-label {
    float: left;
    // ub was 140px
    width: @labelWidth;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: right;
  }
  // Move over all input controls and content
  .controls {
    // Super jank IE7 fix to ensure the inputs in .input-append and input-prepend
    // don't inherit the margin of the parent, in this case .controls
    *display: inline-block;
    // ub was 20px
    *padding-left: @labelPadding;
    // ub was 160px
    margin-left: @labelWidth + @labelPadding;
    *margin-left: 0;
    &:first-child {
      // ub was 160px
      *padding-left: @labelWidth + @labelPadding;
    }
  }
  // Remove bottom margin on block level help text since that's accounted for on .control-group
  .help-block {
    margin-top: @baseLineHeight / 2;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  // Move over buttons in .form-actions to align with .controls
  .form-actions {
   // ub was 160px
    padding-left: @labelWidth + @labelPadding;
  }
}
```

Comment: Never edit library files, as it makes upgrade and maintenance very difficult. -1 for this answer.

Comment: This answer was related to the answer below (which hacked the pixel width) and contains an improvement for bootstrap, as it modified fixed items into a variable. The edit I proposed here is now implemented with @horizontalComponentOffset in the current bootstrap version.

Comment: I downvoted the other answer as well for the same reason, don't worry. I maintain my point. If you wanted to improve the other answer you could have edited it, or commented on it.

Comment: No, I wanted to improve bootstrap :-)